# Не обновляется Web приложение на IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

Использую для проекта ASP.NET Web-Api вместе с планировщиком задач Hangfire.
Версия загруженная от начала этого года, а именно 18.01.2018, работает идеально, но появилась необходимость обновлять код и добавлять новые задачи.

После публикации нового приложения на сервер, и его запуске в IIS, приложение начинает моментально съедать всю ОЗУ и использовать максимальную скорость ЦП, а именно процесс w3wp.exe. Я пробовал отключать в новой версии HangFire не помогло, отключал сторонние задачи которые запускаются с другого приложения так же это не дало результатов. Создавал новый пул приложений, и новый Web сайт, не помогло

Но на тестовой среде все опубликованные приложения, почему - то прекрасно отрабатывают. Порты разные Ip одинаковый. Подскажите куда смотреть? Что это может быть? И если необходим какой либо код, я готов его предоставить.

**UPD_1**

Откатил обновленные версии NuGet пакетов, приложение теперь намертво не зависает, но все равно отъедает все ОЗУ и потом падает, перезагружается и так по кругу

Comment: скопировать дамп боевой БД на тестовую среду, смотреть логи запросов в БД, подключиться профайлером скорости\памяти к процессу, логгировать каждый шаг, что выполняет приложение, найти на каком шаге оно застряло, дебажить код, найти проблему, устранить, профит

Comment: @tym32167 тестовая среда различается лишь портом, БД одна и та же, в БД не успевает уйти не единого запроса, на локальном ПК и тестовым веб приложением с обновлением работает все отлично. Пул использоваемого приложения перезапускал, видел решение с WSUS Pool, такого у себя не нашел

Comment: А само приложение успевает стартовать? Если вместо него выложить пустое приложение, оно номально стартанет?

Comment: @tym32167 пустое приложение стартует, ЦП и ОЗУ не загружает

Comment: ну, тогда наверное дело не в пуле, а в вашем приложении

Comment: @tym32167 ну оно тогда бы загрузило мне и локалку и то же тестовое веб приложение, просто банальной загрузкой в папку другого приложения ничего не изменяется

Comment: У вас есть приложение А (пустое) и приложение Б. На одном и том же хостинге, в том же пуле, с теми же настройками, в той же папке приложение А работает, Б - не работает. То, что Б работает где то там на другом хосте - это уже другой вопрос. Вы логи смотрели? Ваше приложение вообще стартует? Или оно падает ещё ДО старта?

Comment: Приложение работает, я успеваю даже зайти иногда в DashBoard от Hangfire, потом виснет. Можно успеть впринципе выбрать любую страницу куда зайти до того как ОЗУ будет забито

Comment: Раз приложение стартует, то проблема снова в приложении. Я бы отключал функции приложения по одной до тех пор, пока оно не стартанет нормально. чтобы понять, какая из функций сбоит.

Comment: Снимите дамп в момент зависания (обычный task manager умеет это делать). Стяните его на машину, где есть visual studio или хотя бы windbg,  откройте и посмотрите, что ест память.

Comment: Проблему решил, спасибо. Ошибка была в том что это API и определенные функции не вызывались на другом IP, на боевом оно сразу отрабатывалось и цикл вешал всю программу